# Strange duplication of questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've noticed three potentially duplicate questions about creating a left-linear grammar today, one on MSE, two on here. MSE was the first to be asked, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698779/converting-right-linear-grammar-to-left-linear-grammar), then [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54502/convert-a-right-linear-grammar-to-a-left-linear-grammar) nearly identical question was asked on CS.SE, followed up by [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54509/drawing-automaton-for-right-linear-grammar) question about constructing an automaton for the problem. All three questions were asked by unregistered users; I don't know if they're actually identical. How should these questions be handled?

ETA: A [fourth question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54511/regular-expression-of-a-given-language) just showed up.

Answer (score 1):

When the same user asks the same question multiple times, we normally merge them (or just close unanswered copies as duplicates). When the question is asked on different sites, we normally close with a comment or migrate then merge.

But here, these are different users, and the questions are not exactly the same. Evidently these are all about the same homework assignment, but asked by different students who are struggling with different aspects of the assignments.

So I don't think there's anything special to do. These are independent questions on related topics. If there were questions about the same topic, even worded differently, then they should be closed as duplicates; but here the questions are sufficiently distinct that they aren't exact duplicates.

Comment: Makes sense. Do the mods have tools that let them determine whether the users are truly distinct vs. one person creating multiple accounts, or is that not something you worry about?

Comment: [We can never be sure who's who on the Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog), but yes, we have some additional [private](http://cs.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) information. One person creating multiple accounts is [not forbidden per se but most of the behaviors that it allows are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682). The biggest no-no is voting for oneself, but [so is a group systematically voting for each other](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) so being sure that it's the same person isn't critical.